# limit Acts-as-taggable-on to max number

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags

I'm using this gem 
https://github.com/mbleigh/acts-as-taggable-on

VIEW:

```
  <% tag_cloud Cast.tag_counts, %w[s m l] do |tag, css_class| %>
  <%= link_to tag.name, tag_path(tag.name), class: css_class %>
<% end %>
```

Controller:

```
if params[:tag]
  @casts = Cast.tagged_with(params[:tag])
else
  @casts = Cast.all
end
```

I just want to limit to top 20 tags.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do the following in the controller:

```
@casts = Cast.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order('DESC').limit(20)
```

Have a look here, you can create something in the model which you can call in your helpers if you need to use it all over the application:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#ordering

so in your model:

```
  def self.newest
  Model.order('created_at DESC').limit(5).all
  end
```

In your helper call:

```
def newest
 Model.newest
end
```

Then you can use it in your view anywhere:

```
<% newest.each do |new| %>
<%= new.column %>
```

My tip is always play around with this in console first, you will learn alot faster as well :)

Comment: No that didn't work, I tried. IN the view changing Cast.tag_counts to Cast.tag_counts.limit(5) will limit to 5 but will not order them.

Comment: @tehras did that change help. Have a look at the link I gave you, you need to define the order in the model at a database level and then you can also call it from a helper or the model in any part of the application.

Comment: I'm not sure how tag_counts works, it's not a column in the db, so you cant query it.

Comment: Did this not work: @casts = Cast.tagged_with(params[:tag]).order('DESC').limit(20

Comment: The solution was actually very simple:
I changed tag_counts to tag_counts_on, and added order('count desc')

    Cast.tag_counts_on(:tags).order('count desc').limit(20)

Comment: Can you tick answer if it helped please @tehras

Comment: @tehras did my answer help you please click the tick